# Why Windows 7 seems so dumb to me at file copy/cancel operations?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I simply try to copy a few files/folders but Windows 7 calculates the time and the progress bar seems like Knight Rider. When I hit the Cancel button to cancel the operation, it won't be canceled for a long while. If it's USB memory then I simply unplug it. Copy, delete, move or cancel any operation, it randomly takes ages.

This is very annoying and I don't have any clue why Win Vista/7 do that? Is there any better application to replace Explorer for file copy/move/delete operations only?

Comment: Accurately predicting file transfer speeds is actually extremely complicated and difficult to do accurately without using excessive amounts of computational time to estimate it - think of it like weather forecasting.  It's not just that they're lazy and don't want to make it better.  Of course, that said, Microsoft's implementation is still pretty bad compared to some other ones...

Comment: Only time I see this problem is with a lot more than a "few" files.

Comment: @Shiranni: Calculating the time to copy 200 MB files shouldn't be longer than copying 200 MB files.

Comment: @Nime Cloud - That just depends on how accurate you want to be - on modern hardware, getting an estimate accurate to within, say, 5% of the actual transfer time potentially DOES take longer than the actual transfer itself takes. (PS - @ notifications don't work unless you spell the user's name correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php). It has a pretty good reputation.

Comment: I just installed and tried. Thanks a lot. This is very constructive answer, instead of closing the question. I'm not newbie but I wonder why Win 7 acts like a dumb, XP is much better; it starts immediately copying. Happily I heard that Windows 8 will have better/centralized copy/move window. I hope it will be smarter too.

Comment: Improving our file management basics: copy, move, rename, and delete   http://bit.ly/oGvimM

Comment: XP actually closes the dialog long before it actually finishes writing to disk. http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/02/04/2826167.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The delay in canceling is probably due to write caching. (Linux has the same issue.)